# additive measure on countable algebras

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebras, lebesgue-measure

I was wondering, can the following theorem be true for finitely additive measures defined on algebras not $\sigma$-algebras. (Theorem is in Bogachev's Measure Theory Vol I).

[image]

> I was not sure about it, but I found a coubterexample for nonatomic measure, which is: $\lambda=\mu+2\nu$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the unit intrval $I$, and $\nu$ is a 0−1-valued finitely additive measure on $I$ such that $\nu(A)=0$ if $\mu(A)=0$. $\lambda$ is a nonatomic finitely additive measure, but has not partition for $0<\varepsilon<2$.
>
> I really need a result like this: suppose $\mu$ is a **finitely additive nonatomic** measure on a **countable** Boolean algebra $B$. Then,  for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite partition $P$ of the unit element such that $\mu(p_i)<\varepsilon$" for each $p_i\in P$ and $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek do you mean for countable algebra ? or ...

Comment: @Emil: presumably "nonatomic" means: any set with positive measure has a subset with strictly smaller, but still positive, measure.  So ultrafilters are atomic...

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: Ah, yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual proof of this uses countable intersections.  So for a counterexample, we need a case without countable intersections.

Consider the set $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb R$.  Let $U_n, n \in \mathbb N$ be a disjoint set of nonempty open intervals with total measure $1$.  (For example, the intervals that make up the complement of the Cantor set.)  Write $U = \bigcup_n U_n$.  Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of all finite unions of intervals $\subset U$ with rational endpoints.  For $A \in \mathcal A$ let $\mu(A)$ be the Lebesgue measure of $A$.  Note that $0 \le \mu(A) < 1$ for such $A$.  Strictly less, because each such $A$ is contained in a finite union of the sets $U_n$.

Let $\mathcal B$ be the collection of complements $[0,1] \setminus A$ of elements of $\mathcal A$.  If $B \in \mathcal B$, write $B = [0,1]\setminus A$ and define $\mu(B) = 10 - \mu(A)$.  Note that $9 < \mu(B) \le 10$ for such $B$.

Now let $\mathcal F = \mathcal A \cup \mathcal B$.  We should check that $\mathcal F$ is a countable algebra, $\mu$ is additive on $\mathcal F$, nonatomic on $\mathcal F$, and the whole space $[0,1]$ is not a disjoint union of sets with measure $< 9$.

Comment: In the Cantor example, isn't is true that anything is a disjoint union of things with measure $\le 2^{-n}$?

Comment: Sorry I do not get your point. Do you mean my example is also true? or .... Please explain more.

Comment: I mean your example satisfies the "result you need", whereas mine doesn't.